# Fix layout in portrait mode by configuring in XML layout/flApps.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, portrait

I have a FrameLayout flApp.xml.
I would like to use flApp.xml only in portrait mode.

**Can I config in Layout file flApps.xml to work only in portrait mode? **

Note: I don't want to config in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to edit you `AndroidManifest.xml` you can force portrait mode programatically by using

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```